# SQL Server query group dates and amounts

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this table:

```
ID, PayDate  , ActualPayDate , Cost , Price
1 , 18-11-18 , 30-11-18      , 100  , 120
2 , 28-3-19  , 1-4-19        , 150  , 230
3 , 5-4-19   , null          , 170  , 290
4 , 5-3-19   , null          , 100  , 200
```

I want to group the PayDate by year and month for the Cost column and group by the ActualPayDate for the Price, the results should by somthing like this:

```
Year , Month , Cost , Price
2018 , 11    , 100  , 120
2018 , 12    , 0    , 0
2019 , 1     , 0    , 0
2019 , 2     , 0    , 0
2019 , 3     , 250  , 0
2019 , 4     , 170  , 230
```

Please help.

Comment: which DBMS are you using?

Comment: What's the type of PayDate ?

Comment: Create a calendar table (or cte) having all the wanted years and months. OUTER JOIN.

Comment: SQL Server with SSMS

Answer (score 1):

Use `apply`:

```
select year(v.dte), month(v.dte), coalesce(sum(v.cost), 0) as cost,
      coalesce(sum(v.price)) as price
from t cross apply
     (values (t.paydate, t.cost, 0), 
             (t.actualpaydate, 0, t.price)
     ) v(dte, cost, price)
group by year(v.dte), month(v.dte)
order by year(v.dte), month(v.dte);
```

Comment: He's used it to be shorthand for date: i.e. paydate / actual paydate. Where Gordon has cross applied the values (paydate, cost, 0), (actualpaydate, 0, price), he has named those three columns (dte, cost, price) for the cross applied name v.

Answer (score 0):

Please try this sub sql then join with the time diminsion.

```
with CTE as 
(
select Year(PayDate) as [Year] 
    , Month(PayDate) as [Month]
    , Sum(Cost) as [cost] 
    , Sum(Price) as Price
from table
Group by Year(PayDate), Month(PayDate)
)
Select Cte.*,  tblDimTime * from CTE 
Outer join tblDimTime
 on cte.[Year] = cte.[Year]
 and cte.[Month] = cte.[Month]
```

here is link to "Creating a date dimension or calendar table in SQL Server"

https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/4054/creating-a-date-dimension-or-calendar-table-in-sql-server/

Comment: There's missing months where's there's no paydate